# Linux - Run Bash script in background

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

To run this app, there's a long command, so I wrote a script, "start_myapp.sh" and the application starts up fine.

```
#!/bin/sh

LOC="/temp/data/myapp"
JAVA="/bin/java"
$JAVA -Dhome=$LOC -Dsftlogging.configuration=$LOC/myapp.ini -jar $LOC/myapp.jar
```

If I close the terminal, it closes the application.  To get the app to run in the background, I would need to do this, which also works fine

```
nohup /global/myfile/scripts/start_myapp.sh &
```

Now, I would like to put everything in the script.  So when I run the script, "start_myapp.sh" the script would start the application in the background.  This is what I have but it will not work.

If I run this command

```
nohup $($JAVA -Dhome=$LOC -Dsftlogging.configuration=$LOC/myapp.ini -jar $LOC/myapp.jar) &
```

The application will not start up

If I run this command

```
nohup $JAVA -Dhome=$LOC -Dsftlogging.configuration=$LOC/myapp.ini -jar $LOC/myapp.jar &
```

The application starts up but from the logs, it says "Invalid command". So I don't think the application start up correctly.

Comment: Why are you using the `$( )` here? What is it meant to achieve?

Comment: (1) [Quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (2) Where did this `$()` come from and why do you think you need it?

Comment: What mean "This is what I have but it doesn't work." ?

Comment: $(...) serves no purpose but I was trying, hoping it might work but it did not.

Comment: I've updated the ticket.  See above.

Comment: To be absolutely clear: the 5-line script from the top of the question worked when executed as `nohup /global/myfile/scripts/start_myapp.sh &`; but since then you've changed the line 5 (and nothing else, right?) by prepending `nohup ` and postpending `&`, and now if executed (how?), from the logs (what logs?) it says `Invalid command`. Please confirm. What do the logs say when you run it like in the beginning, where it "works fine"?

Answer (score 0):

If I run this command, it runs fine.

```
nohup /global/myfile/scripts/start_myapp.sh &
```

I just would like to incorporate **nohup** and **&** as part of the script.  So it's more convenient.  But it failed everytime regards what I do.  If I add "nohup" and "&" to the script,

```
nohup $JAVA -Dhome=$LOC -Dsftlogging.configuration=$LOC/myapp.ini -jar $LOC/myapp.jar &
```

Now if I run the script,

```
/global/myfile/scripts/start_myapp.sh
```

The application starts up but in the application logs, I'm bombarded with "Invalid Command".  That's all it says, which is very vague.  I'm thinking it might be a syntax error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).